# Align content to top of sheet instead of middle

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way with SwiftUI to align content directly to the top of a sheet instead of in the middle?

My sheet is just a simple `Text` view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a spacer to move it at top, like

```
VStack {
  Text("Your text")
  Spacer()           // << here !!
}
```

Comment: Just one of those days... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way beside Spacer() too:

```
    VStack {
        Text("Hello World!")
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    }
```

[image]